# I'm trying to make a graph with javafx and I am getting the error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application

Tags: java, spring, javafx, error-handling, runtime

so I am quite new to javafx and I am struggling with some packages (I think)

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    // Defining the axes
    CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    xAxis.setCategories(
            FXCollections.<String>observableArrayList(Arrays.asList("Speed", "User rating", "Milage", "Safety")));
    xAxis.setLabel("category");

    NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    yAxis.setLabel("score");

    // Creating the Bar chart
    BarChart<String, Number> barChart = new BarChart<>(xAxis, yAxis);
    barChart.setTitle("Comparison between various cars");

    // Prepare XYChart.Series objects by setting data
    XYChart.Series<String, Number> series1 = new XYChart.Series<>();
    series1.setName("Fiat");
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Speed", 1.0));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("User rating", 3.0));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Milage", 5.0));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Safety", 5.0));

    XYChart.Series<String, Number> series2 = new XYChart.Series<>();
    series2.setName("Audi");
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Speed", 5.0));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("User rating", 6.0));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Milage", 10.0));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Safety", 4.0));

    XYChart.Series<String, Number> series3 = new XYChart.Series<>();
    series3.setName("Ford");
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Speed", 4.0));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("User rating", 2.0));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Milage", 3.0));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>("Safety", 6.0));

    // Setting the data to bar chart
    barChart.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3);

    // Creating a Group object
    Group root = new Group(barChart);

    // Creating a scene object
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 400);

    // Setting title to the Stage
    stage.setTitle("Bar Chart");

    // Adding scene to the stage
    stage.setScene(scene);

    // Displaying the contents of the stage
    stage.show();
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

this is my sample code to create a bar chart and I received the error "JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application". I then added an vmargument to my config. Since I use vscode I entered

"vmArgs": "--module-path /C:/Documents/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml",

into the launch.json. After that though, I get the error

"Error occurred during initialization of boot layer java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 2: /C:/Documents/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib"

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I figured out, the address I used to add the modules in vmarguments were actually wrong, and fixed it immediately after.